# Unable to save a new Contact through a custom VisualForce form

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, community

Using VisualForce & APEX to submit a new Contact record. Generating a custom form and trying to save the records as a new 'Contact' on my SF instance.

Once I click on 'Save' button below error is generated

[image]

**VisualForce Page code**

```
<apex:page Controller="ContactController" >
    <apex:form >

        <apex:pageBlock title="New Contact Form">

            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                <apex:inputField value="{!c.FirstName}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!c.LastName}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!c.Email}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!c.Birthdate}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
          <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!samepage}" var="c">
          <apex:column headerValue="First Name">
          <apex:outputField value="{!c.Firstname}"/>
          </apex:column>

          <apex:column headerValue="Last Name">
          <apex:outputField value="{!c.Lastname}"/>
          </apex:column>

          <apex:column headerValue="Birthdate">
          <apex:outputField value="{!c.Birthdate}"/>
          </apex:column>
          </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>

    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**APEX Controller Code**

public with sharing class ContactController {

```
public Contact c { get; set; }

public List<Contact> samepage { get; set; }

//Constructor
public ContactController(){
   c=new Contact();
}

public PageReference save() {
```

//        Database.DMLOptions dml = new Database.DMLOptions();
    //    dml.DuplicateRuleHeader.AllowSave = true;
        Database.SaveResult sro = Database.insert(c, false);

```
        if(sro.isSuccess()) {  
        // Operation was successful, so get the ID of the record that was processed  
        System.debug('Successfully inserted contact. Contact ID: ' + sro.getId());  
        }  
        else {  
            // Operation failed, so get all errors  
            for(Database.Error err : sro.getErrors()) {  
            System.debug('The following error has occurred.');  
            System.debug(err.getStatusCode() + ': ' + err.getMessage());  
            System.debug('Account fields that affected this error: ' + err.getFields());  
            }  
        }  

    return null;
```

}
}

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a rule set up in your org to disallow duplicate emails. If that is there intentionally, and you want to keep it, here are a couple of options:

- Improve the error handling in your controller by putting a `try`/`catch` around the `insert c` and using `c.addError(ex);` to better report the error via an `apex:pageMessages` in the Visualforce
- Include more active logic in your controller (i.e. do a query to check) to tell the user they are duplicating an existing email address

Comment: `Database.insert(records, false)` avoids the need of try-catch, though, and also presents a nice error on Visualforce pages.

Comment: Didn't know that - worth a separate answer.

Comment: @sfdcfox tried above its not working. Its neither inserting new contact nor displaying any error.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public PageReference save() {
       Database.DMLOptions dml = new Database.DMLOptions(); 
       dml.DuplicateRuleHeader.AllowSave = true; 
       Database.SaveResult sro = Database.insert(c, dml);
       if(sro.isSuccess()) {  
        System.debug('Successfully inserted contact. Contact ID: ' + sro.getId());  
       }  
       else {  
            for(Database.Error err : sro.getErrors()) {  
              System.debug('The following error has occurred.');  
              System.debug(err.getStatusCode() + ': ' + err.getMessage());  
              System.debug('Account fields that affected this error: '+err.getFields());  
            }  
       }      
       return null;
    }
```

I've replaced false with dml in your save method

Comment: tried above code, it's not inserting neither any error message. Please check updated controller code in my question.

Comment: Replace false with dml(in insert statement)